# DNN page render correctly in IE7/Vista

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-7, dotnetnuke

I have a dot net nuke site that I have written a custom module for.  It a form that users fill out to submit information - no big deal.

On the form, I use the Ajax and the Ajaxoolkit for validation, and a calendar popup. I enable/disable controls based on form data.

Everthing works well in every browser/OS combo that I have tested EXCEPT IE7/Vista.

The page renders with most of the lables and conrols invisible.  The controls are there and you can even enter data, you just can see them.

Here is a link:  http://www.gpusbc.com/test/tabid/76/Default.aspx

I develop on a Win XP machine with IE7 and FireFox and there are no problems.
FireFox on Vista has no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI this doesn't work in IE8 on Vista in regular or in compatiblity mode. This is incredibly weird because the controls are there you can click in them but your textboxes for example if you type you don't see the data.

What I've found is that if you remove the float:left style which is inherited from the .aaInput class that all of your inputs become visible. I also removed your display of 
block. Do this on both the labels and your inputs and you should be good.

I tested this with IE8's developer tools in both IE8 mode and compatibility mode.

Comment: That works! Thank you! The form looks pretty good in IE7/Vista.  However, it no longer looks right in FireFox.  The labels are not a uniform width.

Comment: I'd right align your labels this will make them uniform. If this solved your problem don't forget to make this as the correct answer;-)

Comment: Ok, I got it.  I removed the display:block but I left the float:left there.  This way it renders correctly in IE7/Vista IE7/WinXP and FF.